# Spring integration not transforming ByteMessage

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-integration, spring-jms, spring-integration-dsl

I have a JMS listener which is receiving ByteMessage from another application. The current application is working with Spring JMS. I am trying to introduce spring integration here. So I added the following sample code to listen for the message.

```
@Configuration
public class JmsConfiguration {

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow integrationFlow(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory) {

    return IntegrationFlows
            .from(Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter(connectionFactory)
                    .destination("fooQueue"))
                    .transform("hello "::concat)
                    .get();
}
```

Then I am getting the class cast exception as below:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: [B cannot be cast to java.lang.String
```

I am getting a ByteMessage and I am not finding a good example on how the ByteMessage with Byte array payload can be extracted. I am new to the spring integration world.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `.transform(Transformers.objectToString())` before your `.transform()`. `BytesMessage` will result in a message with a `byte[]` payload so you need to convert it to a `String` before trying to concatenate it.

Comment: The question sounds misleading. Spring Integration's `Jms.messageDrivenChannelAdapter()` comes with a `SimpleMessageConverter` by defualt. See JavaDocs `jmsMessageConverter(MessageConverter messageConverter)` of that Spec and docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/jms.html#jms-inbound-channel-adapter. So, Spring Integration does convert `ByteMessage`, but it indeed produces a `byte[]` as it is confirmed with that `ClassCastException`.